# MySQL insert into two related tables with data from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My MySQL database has 3 tables like these:

> **COURSE** (*"course_id"* AUTO_INCREMENT, course_title, create_date, ...)
>
> **USER** (*"user_id"*, usename, ...)
>
> **CREATE_COURSE** (*"user_id"*, *"course_id"*, create_date, ... )

Constraints:

> **CREATE_COURSE.course_id** REFERENCES **COURSE.course_id**
>
> **CREATE_COURSE.user_id** REFERENCES **USER.course_id**

In my PHP site, I 've already had all needed information to insert to table **COURSE** as well as the **user_id**

Now, My PHP `create_course($course_title, $create_date)` function can insert data to table **COURSE**.
I want to also insert corresponding data (`user_id`, `course_id`) to table **CREATE_COURSE**.

Can anyone suggest me a way to automatically do that because I don't want to manually insert data into both **COURSE** and **CREATE_COURSE** tables within `create_course` function

P/S: I used to think about `create_course($course_id, $course_title, $create_date)`. However, since `$course_id` is AUTO_INCREMENT, this function does not seem to work properly.

Comment: why cant you use 2 mysql querys?

Comment: insert into course - grab id, insert into user - grab id ... pass user_id and course_id to create_course

Comment: Why do you not *want* to manually insert it? If you want to insert stuff into multiple tables then you have to make multiple insertions.

Comment: Yeah. That seems reasonable @SverriM.Olsen . Maybe, my question was just stupid

Comment: @DucCuong Not stupid, just a little odd. And just as a note: Using a transaction would make sense, if the data is relational.

Comment: You could try triggers (although I don't work with it) if you don't want to do it with PHP like [in here](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/) (AFTER INSERT Trigger). Just that you would need an extra select query there to get the `user_id`.

Comment: I don't think he needs an extra select query, it's only `mysqli_insert_id()` that he will need to use a few times.